# d3 js graph going flowing out of grid lines

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to using d3js to build graphs. My current task is charting no of logs across time. So my Y axis is logs and x axis is time. For some data, the graph comes fine within the grid line, but for some where the data is huge, it flows out of the grids like below. Also even if I am charting 3 or 4 days in the past, I only see 2 days on the axis. Below also the code that I use for setting height. I'm using time scale on x axis and linear scale on y axis.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select(".content").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
```

How can I set the height and width to be according to the data?

[image]

Comment: Can we see your scales? e.g. `d3.scale.linear()...` etc. How do you actually define your `x` and `y`?

Comment: Are you using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 as a basis for this chart? Can you provide the full code with your data transformation (and a data sample)?

Comment: @Oleg yes I am using the example as the basis for the chart. I tried setting height and width to the width of the parent container but that doesn't help. Here is my fiddle with sample data http://jsfiddle.net/JYS8n/2/.

Comment: Your `Value` properties in the data array are strings. You should convert them to numbers in your `forEach` as in the example on bl.ocks.org. For example: `d.Value = +d.Value;` Otherwise it's alphabetic min/max where `"2000" < "3" // true`

Comment: @Oleg that's great. I thought I had done it already but I was only parsing date and not value. That conversion did the trick. That said, how do I make the overlap each other using the same scale. After parsing to int, I get the two line but not overlapping though the data overlaps.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping"?

Comment: @Oleg so i am trying to build multiple lines though the fiddle i sent only shows only line, like the bl.ocks example you showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63243/discussion-between-oleg-and-ash).